Someone was trapped in a room and got out by a picture of a ship
I remember parts from the movie. This movie was most probably from before 2012. Not sure if the main char was a man or a woman. In this he/she crawls across the ledge of a building into another room, which was completely white I think, then they find that they are trapped. Various things happen in the room, I think that in a part it suddenly becomes cold, and the character was shivering. In the end, they manage to escape by touching a picture of a ship or something, water floods in and they find themselves at a beach or something. Then they enter a bar (not sure if a bar) and men start breaking it with hammers, and the main char is trapped again. In the end there was a fire or something.

That's the Stephen King adaption 1408 - Watch the trailer on Youtube

@Oliver_C and Nicholas Aysen Thanks so much! This is certainly what I was looking for.

The movie in question is 1408 starring John Cusack. The scenes you are describing are his attempts to escape. The beach scene in question is when he thought he got out.
Here is a plot extract of the scenes in question

  The room shakes violently and Mike breaks a picture of a ship in a storm. Water pours from the broken picture, flooding the room. He surfaces on a beach and relives a surfing accident seen earlier in the film. His life continues from this point, and he reconciles with Lily. Eventually he assumes his experience in 1408 was just a dream. Lily persuades him to write a book about it. When visiting the post office to send the manuscript to his publisher, he recognizes members of a construction crew as the Dolphin Hotel staff. They destroy the post office walls, revealing Mike is still trapped in 1408. A vision of Katie appears to Mike, and after some reluctance he embraces her; she crumbles to dust. 

